# MSBuild Messages for c++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

**Problem:** Editings .props files with msbuild is failing. I'd like to see what the intermediate results of operations are doing with some output message. " is not supported" is the what the IDE is telling me.

**Example:**
 I want to get the last four characters of the configuration name to use a part of a string.

```
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
        <Import project=".\prop_$(Configuration.Substring($([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Configuration.Length),4)) )).props" />    
  </ImportGroup>
```

*How can I see the results of the parts, the length, the subtract, the substring?* I want to be able to print out these values during the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Message Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx)

example:
At the top of the project set InitialTargets to the name of your Target

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="DisplayText">

<Target Name="DisplayText">
   <Message Importance="high" Text="Configuration = $(Configuration)" />
   <Message Importance="high" Text="Configuration Length = $(Configuration.Length)" />
   <Message Importance="high" Text="Configuration Substring = $(Configuration.Substring($([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Configuration.Length),4))))" />
</Target>
```

That should print out everything you asked about during the build process.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TemplateTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Configuration = Debug
1>  Configuration Length = 5
1>  Configuration Substring = ebug
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the IDE and it doesn't seem to work in c++ builds. Where in the vcxproj would this go that doesn't cause a messagebox to pop up saying how it's not supported? And where would the output show up?

Comment: @BenL please look at the edited answer, it worked for me assuming the 'Text' is set up properly based on yourconfiguration